# What to do after removing a gem from the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I removed a gem 'mygem' from the Gemfile, but just now I realized it's still installed.

So how do I tell bundler to rescan the Gemfile and update Gemfile.lock, **without** updating every gem?

Coming from php, this is how I'm used to do this: `composer update nothing`. Is there an equivalent for bundler?

Answer (score 48):

You can run just `bundle` or `bundle install` to install gems based on your Gemfile. That will  remove the instance of `mygem` from your Gemfile.lock file. It will not, however, remove the gem from your system. To do that, run `gem uninstall mygem`.

Not completely related, but still helpful:

- `bundle outdated` will show you the gems that aren't on the latest version. Don't get *too* tied up with this list - it's fairly common to have gems that aren't on the latest version, because some gems are installed as dependencies & one gem might be requiring an older version of another gem.
- `bundle upgrade mygem` will upgrade *just* that gem, and will bring its dependencies up to date. That means that other gems might be upgraded or installed as well.
- You can search [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) to see a gem's dependencies across each of its versions. As a gem user, you'll only need to be concerned with the 'Runtime Dependencies' list at the bottom of the gem's page.

Comment: There is also very handy `bundle clean` command to automatically remove old and unused gems. Does work with Bundler >= 1.1 and if gems were installed with `--path` option.

Comment: Oh, cool! I've been using `gem cleanup` ... Any idea how the two differ?

Comment: I like comprehensive answers like these

Comment: `bundle install --clean`
See the official documentation: https://bundler.io/v1.15/man/bundle-install.1.html

Answer (score -3):

Cleans up unused gems in your bundler directory:
bundle clean --force

Comment: This removed all the gems from my other repositories

Comment: yeah do not do this. it removes *everything* not just the gems in your project

Comment: This answer needs to be removed. It's misleading.