# Rails app issuing GET requests for /cable route even though ActionCable has been entirely removed from app and system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I want to remove ActionCable from my Rails app, and I found [this](https://blog.sundaycoding.com/blog/2016/08/10/how-to-remove-action-cable-from-a-rails-app/) which says to replace `gem rails` in the Gemfile with all of `rails` component gems *minus* `gem 'action_cable'`. I did this and I manually removed action cable from gemfile.lock

```
# gem 'rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'activerecord', '5.2.0'
gem 'activemodel', '5.2.0'
gem 'actionpack', '5.2.0'
gem 'actionview', '5.2.0'
gem 'actionmailer', '5.2.0'
gem 'activejob', '5.2.0'
gem 'activesupport', '5.2.0'
gem 'railties', '5.2.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
```

**Gemfile.lock**:

```
rails (5.2.0)
 #bye bye action cable
 actionmailer (= 5.2.0)
 actionpack (= 5.2.0)
 actionview (= 5.2.0)
 activejob (= 5.2.0)
 activemodel (= 5.2.0)
 activerecord (= 5.2.0)
 activestorage (= 5.2.0)
 activesupport (= 5.2.0)
 bundler (>= 1.3.0)
 railties (= 5.2.0)
 sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

To be on the safe side, I used the *very emotionally relevant right now* `rake assets:clobber` command. But when I start my server, the logs indicate that something related to actioncable is still present:

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2020-04-26 17:25:08 -0700      
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/cable"):
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:151:in `block in call'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
rack-timeout (0.6.0) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:150:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:682:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I even ran `gem uninstall action_cable` and deleted all versions from my system. Why is it haunting me? ActionCable has turned into an unsolvable hassle.

Comment: As a hint, Rails provides an option for `rails new` command which skips ActionCable entirely. Try generating a new Rails app with `rails new --skip-action-cable` and comparing config files.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, if you remove the gem from your gemfile, and run `bundle install`, it will install only gems from your gemfile and *should* have updated `gemfile.lock`, but it will not uninstall gem from your system.

But you have to remove the gem from the system by calling `gem install <gemname>`.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796395/609782)

Comment: i don't want the gem uninstalled from my system, i just want it gone from the app

Comment: Well I think the gem is not there in your app, and the error says the same thing that it can't find the route matching something that gem added. Can you check where this route was being added?

Comment: i manually removed the actioncable lines from gemfile.lock, but my terminal is still issuing GET requests for `/cable`. the route is absent from routes.rb and there's nothing in config/environments/development. the javascript consumer for `/cable` has been deleted. 

Comment: Since you might be using this for WebSocket connections. Can you think of a place where you might be making this connection. ie calling this `/cable` endpoint? Because now I think it has nothing to do with the gem anymore.

Comment: the *only* place in my app that i can find `/cable` is in `project/public/assets/application-cb2f49c93027e42a4e91ee8884b9258e8f67476549371f58986eb1674f121e98.js`. should it not be there?

Comment: i just went and uninstalled every version of the gem from my system to see what would happen. no dice. i've updated my question with complete stack trace of the error

Answer (score 1):

ActionCable should be disabled (not removed) in your config/application.rb file:

```rb
# config/application.rb

# Comment the below line out to disable ActionCable
require "action_cable/engine"
```

Comment: hmmm, the link i included in the op says that there is no need to install action cable as a dependency if it's not going to be used. it provides two options for removing it - what i did, and what you are suggesting. i've tried both!

Comment: Some things you could try: 1) Try enabling ActionCable, then putting a debug in your ActionCable channel to see what's calling it. 2) Grep your app folder for "cable" and see what comes back: `grep -ri /app cable|less` from the CLI